# Checking different certificates for different endpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx

We have a web application that serves both secure and public endpoints. We are currently deploying it with elastic beanstalk.

From now on, we want to apply client certification for secure endpoints. i.e. for some endpoints, certification check is needed.

However, elastic load balancer has not any configuration to assign different ssl certificates for different routes.

The only solution that we found is; setting up nginx instances before the application load balancer and check certificates in here.

Is there a way to achive this on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not personally used one yet, I believe the new Application Load Balancers might be able to handle this.  You can do different types of listeners depending on the request.   So it's definitely worth looking into before you go the nginx route:

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

You can test one out by going into your EC2 services panel, and create a new load balancer.   Choose the Application Load Balancer type and see if you can configure it as needed.

Comment: Thank you Rick, ALB might be useful if we can configure different types of listeners independently, and routing them to different endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Authenticating clients with client certificates require all of the SSL to be handled by the instances themselves.

Load balancing such a setup requires either a Classic ELB in TCP mode (transparent, no HTTP interpretation, with SSL not configured on the balancer)... or a Network Load Balancer, which would probably be the optimal configuration since it is handled by the network infrastructure itself, and is essentially infinitely scalable with no warm-up required.

Elastic Beanstalk [recently announced support for Network Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/aws-elastic-beanstalk-now-supports-network-load-balancer/).

Comment: Thank you Michael, unfortunately network layer balancer currently does not support ssl offloading as you can see: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/details/#details

Comment: Since we need to differentiate secure/unsecure connections with respect to endpoints, routes; I believe it is reasonable to expect the solution in application layer. Network layer balancer even does not support SSL as it is accepted protocol.